# How to subtract datetime with multiple choice values

Tags: python, django

I am thinking of a way of calculating the date by subtracting values in multiple choice filed with current date

I have a model which has multiple choices with values that I want to subtract with datetime.datetime.now but I am not sure how it should be done.

```
REMINDER_CHOICES = (
    (5,'5 minutes before'),
    (15, '15 minutes before'),
    (30, '30 minutes before'),
    (60, '1 hour before'),
    (120, '2 hours before'),
    (240, '4 hours before'),
    (1440, '1 day before'),
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just substract a timedelta like this:

```
date_b = date_a - datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)
```

or

```
date_b = date_a - datetime.timedelta(days=2, minutes=30)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use dateutil to add and substract from datetime. for eg..

```
    import dateutil.relativedelta
    datetime.datetime.now() + dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(day=5)
```

if you want to substract then:

```
    datetime.datetime.now() + dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(day=-5)
```